# Why doesn't the copy of a list in a function work?

Tags: python, list, function

```
b = [0]

def copyalist(b):
    b = [1, 2, 3]
    print(b)

copyalist(b)
print(b)
```

The outputs are below:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[0]
```

The first line indicates that in the function, b was set to [1, 2, 3];
However, when you print(b) out of the function,the second output says that b is still [0].

I don't understand that, why the outer b is not changed?

I also tried b = copy.deepcopy([1, 2, 3]), the outputs are the same.

However, the following code works well:

```
b = [0]

def copyalist(b):
    b += [1, 2, 3]
    print(b)

copyalist(b)
print(b)
```

The outputs are below:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Because in your first example, your funciton does not return any thing, just prints a list that you defined inside it, once the call comes back it print the original `b` list which had `[0]`. Nothing magic in it. Nothing being copied either.

Comment: In your second snippet, again you are only concatenating/merging the list with the previous one. nothing being copied.

Comment: You have two entirely unrelated variables named `b`: a global one, and a local one inside `copyalist()`.  The local `b`'s initial value is the same as the global `b`, but that changes once you assign a new value to the local `b`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Make sure you undertand the difference between global and local variables. In addition, it is not a good practice to alter globals inside the function scope.

Comment: Your question seems to come down to two things. Pass by reference and pass by value; and mutable and immutable types. I suggest to read into that, as well as the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
def copyalist(b):
    b = [1, 2, 3]
    print(b)
```

will only mean to remap the variable name `b` to a new list, but not modifying the original `b`.  If you mean to modify the original list, you have to explicitly tell Python to replace the actual content. The way to do is:

```
def copyalist(b):
    b[:] = [1, 2, 3]
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, lists are passed as function arguments only by reference, i.e., only the memory address of the first element is given. When defining a new `b` inside the function, you just change the position in memory to which the inner variable `b` refers, but the outer `b` still points to the original position. Vice versa, when you do `b += [1, 2, 3]`, you change the content inside the cell referenced by the inner `b` and, since inner and outer `b` point to the same cells, it reflects in a change of the outer `b` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
b = copyalist(b)
```

and return b in the function

```py
def copyalist(b):
    b = [1, 2, 3]
    return(b)
```

When you are defining something in a function it is only used inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a difference in global and local variables. You can add global to your function to get the desired result.

```
b = [0]

def copyalist():
    global b
    b = [1, 2, 3]
    print(b)

copyalist()
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

A more in depth summary is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)